# Bulma CSS full height content

Tags: css, laravel, layout, bulma

I am using [Bulma](https://bulma.io/) (inside a Laravel app) as my CSS framework of choice, and I'm trying to implement a full height content within my page, but am unable to do so.

I am using a hero element here because I like the layout, and here is the code:

```
<section class="hero is-info is-fullheight is-bold">

    @include('partials/header')

    <div class="hero-body">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box">
                test test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @include('partials/footer')

</section>
```

I would like the box to be at 100% of container height, but `height: 100%` does nothing here. Here is the end result I have, and in red the result I want:

[image]

I am building a chat application, so my idea for the `box` element was to be as sort of container where I could stack chat bubbles and see the conversation.

Comment: Add class `is-fullheight` to your `<div class="box">` ?

Comment: Already tried it...it does nothing. Also container needs to be stretched first, and adding it to container doesn't help as well so I presume something custom needs to be done

Comment: Use `height: 100vh;` instead of `100%` for the `is-fullheight` class? Can you make a codepen or something to play around with? Also make sure your `<body>` is full height

Comment: As others have said already, there is a class for this in Bulma, see the specific docs at https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/hero/#sizes